# 2 tail -f with different command

Tags: bash, parsing, logging

I'm trying to make a shell script to monitor a log file, but I have a problem which is I can't do two tail at the same time.
the script basically is to search for a word if it matches it will redirect the 3 lines include the matched word into a file then I will pruning the useless information to extract what I want.
I tried the commands below and it's working fine but when I mirage it in a file it doesn't work 
please advise :) 
below is a part of the script,

```
  #!/bin/bash
    #grep error log
    tail -f /FileLogging.log  | grep  'error' >>/home/hello/tech.txt
    #pruning useless information 
    tail -f /home/hello/tech.txt perl -nle "print $1 if /sam-(.+?)\",\"jack/" >>/home/hello/non.txt
```

Comment: `|` missing before `perl`?

Comment: put the first one into background: `tail -f /FileLogging.log  | grep  'error' >>/home/hello/tech.txt &`

Comment: Or just pipe the three commands together.

Answer (score 0):

Now I detected, the there only one source is watched. So this command should combine both of your example:

```
tail -f /FileLogging.log | grep 'error' | tee -a /home/hello/tech.txt | perl ... >>/home/hello/non.txt
```

Comment: beware of buffering issue it may or may not happen but it is still a thing.